# What's the difference between the output of an oscilloscope and the waveform I get when I record on Praat?

Tags: phonetics, acoustic-analysis, praat

I know it's probably a dumb question, but is this the same thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Though I haven't worked with an oscilloscope directly but I presume both are the same.
[image: sine wave in oscilloscope]

sine wave in oscilloscope

[image: sine wave in Praat]

sine wave in Praat